# How do I safely allow my users to connect to my database?

Tags: database, security

I have created a desktop application that users can download and run from their own machines. This application requires network access and will often send changes to a database (hosted on my server) with updates, inserts, etc.

Keeping a password directly in the application is no good because if the application is decompiled then the user can see the database's credentials and gain full access on their own.

Is the only safe way to do this using GET and POST and an API on the server side? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 2 issues here: 1) Authenticating users issuing POST updates to your server side PHP/database (they are who they say they are) and 2) Preventing your database credentials from being exposed.

1) Are you authenticating users with a 3rd party intergrated server like LDAP?

2) The server credentials shouldn't be stored in the application because they are never needed there. Once you authenticate a user and their request, your server side PHP should have a security function which decrypts the DB credentials and issues the SQL statement based on the information submitted by the user.

So to answer your question, yes, it is best practice to host a server side framework to handle incoming requests, which authenticates the user and then executes their request.

I suppose if you wanted the desktop app to be able to directly update the DB (not recommended), you could store an encrypted hash of the DB credentials and use a decryption algorithm to decrypt and then send them to the database.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['query'])) {
        $query = $_POST['query'];
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

        //Execute SQL
        if($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
            $mysqli->close();
            echo "successful";
        } else { echo "SQL execution error"; }
    } else { 
        echo "invalid query string"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: The authentication is a bit of a separate issue (since it doesn't matter to me who issues the request) but, yes, #2 was what I was getting at. 

As far as storing the hash, though, unless you store the decryption algorithm on your server it is still insecure.

Comment: This is true... If PHP is installed on your server, it could be as simple as one PHP page which receives a _POST['query'] string constructed in the desktop application and executes it with the database credentials stored on the server side.

Comment: Updated answer with the simplest of PHP pages :)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you build a proxy webservice ?
Your client application send the requests, your webservice grab them and securely execute them on your database.

Comment: That's what I assumed the correct practice was. I was mostly curious if there was another way to handle it without exposing information.